# React doesn't prevent form submit in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, frontend

Facing one problem with my component that I can not solve using React 15 . Everything works as expected, except in IE 11.

Basically looks like IE 11 is ignoring the event.preventDefault() function  (and all of the commented functions in the code below, tried with all of them) and submits the data. The page gets reloaded and the query parameters are in the url. I would like to prevent the reloading of the page and execute just the logic in the handleSubmit function.

The form in the render function:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input ref="email" type="email" name="username" required></input>
   <input ref="pass" type="password" name="pass"required></input>
   <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

and this is the hanleSubmit function:

```
handleSubmit: function (event) {

   event.preventDefault();
   //event.returnValue = false;
   //event.stopPropagation();
   //event.nativeEvent.preventDefault(); 

   var email = this.refs.email.value;
   var pass = this.refs.pass.value;

   //return false;
},
```

Comment: Try replace the `event.preventDefault()` with `event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);`. I know that that's for > IE8 but IE is a surprise sometimes.

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Gjoshevski did you end up finding a fix for this?

Comment: I was unable to get form submits to work in IE 11. I resorted to - removing the onSubmit, changing the input to a type=button, and add an onClick to the button that calls what the form does.

Comment: @Gjoshevski, can you check the console using F12 and see if there are some JS errors/warnings ?

Answer (score 0):

The function `preventDefault()` should work fine in **Internet Explorer 11**, however you may be facing another problem in your script that triggers an error/warning that causes `preventDefault()` not to be called.

I recommend to check the console using F12 and see if there are some JS warnings.